# How can I get a Row in flutter to fill the entire space without overflowing?

Tags: flutter, dart

I always have problems with UI in flutter, especially when going to rows/colums and their size. Basically what I have is A Row with a picture and a column in it. The first thing I want to have is a Row with MainAxisAllignment.Spacebetween, so that TextA and TextB are as far away from each other as possible. I cannot have two columns, because then the TextD, which can be pretty long, would push TextB off screen. i tried around with some expanded, flexible and mainaxissize, but I have honestly no idea how this should be done.

Usually I'd MSPaint but I'm on a Mac and don't know of anything as perfect as paint, so here my beautiful Drawing of what it looks like. the 'should' state will be TextB on the different end of the inner row

```
|---------------------------------------------------|
|  I  |--------------------------------------------||
|  M  |  |TextATextB|                              ||
|  A  |  |-Row------|                              ||
|  G  |  TextC                                     ||
|  E  |  TextD                                     ||
|     |-Column-------------------------------------||
|-Row-----------------------------------------------|
```

```dart
Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(
            picture,
            height: 63,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 6,
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(_viewModel.time),
                  Text(_viewModel.session),
                ],
              ),
              Text(_viewModel.room),
              SizedBox(
                height: 2,
              ),
              Text(
                _viewModel.title,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 1,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

And this is the code on how I did this widget. Thanks!

edit: with Excel i made  a hopefully not confusing version. basically: i wanna make the row as long as the column is wide
[image]

Comment: Can you use Microsoft Excel or something similar to describe the UI? I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: @hisam did that excatly, am not sure if it is what you meant

Comment: @MaritnGe  u should use `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max` which will make the row take the full horizontal space

Comment: Have you tried ```CrossAxisAlignment.stretch``` on the outermost ```Column``` ?

Comment: @AhmedKhattab that was my first idea too, but it dodsnt change a thing in either rows

Comment: what about wrapping the inner `Row` with an `Expanded` widget?\

Comment: @AhmedKhattab that gives an `'RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.'` and everything next to the image is empty

Comment: as @Naslausky suggests, you can use `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` for the green column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a neat question. As per the requirement, **you have done most of the parts**, some improvements were missing, hence, I am adding this into your code.

1. `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` is the key
2. Make sure to use `Expanded` and wrap it around your `Column` to work

Final solution:

```
            // I have not used your data, just used mine for image, texts
            Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.network(
                   "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
                    height: 63.0,
                    width: 63.0
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 6.0),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text('Text A'),
                            Text('Text B'),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Text('Text C'),
                        SizedBox(height: 2.0),
                        Text(
                          'Text D',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          maxLines: 1,
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                        ),
                      ]
                    )
                  )
                ]
              )
```

Result you will get is:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve something like this, then the following code snippet will help you.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXLvF.png)

```
IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
      Image.network(
        "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/young-man-at-sunset-picture-id496261146?s=612x612",
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        height: 69,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 6,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("time"),
                Text("session"),
              ],
            ),
            Text("room"),
            SizedBox(
              height: 2,
            ),
            Text(
              "How can I get a Row in flutter to fill the entire space without overflowing?",
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 1,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ]),
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the image, here's my code:

```
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(child: Image(/*Your Image Here*/)),

          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row( // THIS IS BLUE AND LIGHT BLUE ROW THAT SHOW UP IN THE IMAGE
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(/*THIS IS YOUR BLUE ROW*/),
                  Container(/*THIS IS YOUR LIGHT BLUE ROW*/),
                ],
              ),

              Row( // THIS IS ANOTHER BLUE AND LIGHT BLUE ROW THAT DON'T SHOW UP IN THE IMAGE
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(/*THIS IS YOUR ANOTHER BLUE ROW*/),
                  Container(/*THIS IS YOURANOTHER LIGHT BLUE ROW*/),
                ],
              ),

              // ADD MORE ROW HERE

            ],
          ),

        ],
      ),
```

But I still don't add the `MainAxisAlignment` or `CrossAxisAlignment`. And it might still don't looks like the image. But, I've done the core foundation of it.